# PhoneCallbacks Firebase :: Class 'PhoneCallbacks' is not abstract and does not implement

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Okay so I got this code from another developer(I know PHP, web development and I am not that experienced with android and firebase) he gave me this code with some outdated SDKs and libraries so I updated them but now one of the kotlin files keep throwing this error and i don't know how to fix it can anyone help

```
class PhoneCallbacks(private val listener : PhoneCallbacksListener) : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    interface PhoneCallbacksListener {
        fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential?)
        fun onVerificationFailed(exception: FirebaseException?)
        fun onCodeSent(
                verificationId: String?,
                token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken?
        )
    }

    override fun onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential: PhoneAuthCredential?) {
        listener.onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential)
    }

    override fun onVerificationFailed(exception: FirebaseException?) {
        listener.onVerificationFailed(exception)
    }

    override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String?, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken?) {
        listener.onCodeSent(verificationId,token)
    }
}
```

The Error:

> PhoneCallBacks.kt: (6, 1): Class 'PhoneCallbacks' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential): Unit defined in com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

Comment: Have you tried to do what the error message says?

Comment: i mean well yeah but then it just throws more errors

Comment: Hi srry bud i was really busy i will check it out in a bit then report back to you. thank you for your help and i hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'v declared `onVerificationCompleted` as:

```
override fun onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential: PhoneAuthCredential?) {
```

But the actual [interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks) defines the `onVerificationCompleted` as non-optional, so:

```
override fun onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
```